# ¿Cómo adquirió "taco" el significado de "palabrota"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa

"Decir tacos" es una forma coloquial de expresar que alguien está diciendo palabrotas (palabras malsonantes, groseras u ofensivas).

El DRAE recoge esa acepción [con la entrada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YvQrYuw)

> 19. m. coloq. Voto, juramento, palabrota. Echar, soltar tacos.

Buscando sobre la etimología de taco, no encuentro demasiado. La mayoría de las referencias se centran en el significado de "[trozo de madera](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?taco.n)" y unas pocas menos en el origen del término que da nombre al [plato de cocina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taco).

No es sorprendente que para la acepción que viene del habla coloquial sea más difícil rastrear el origen, pero es que no estoy teniendo ninguna suerte con los resultados de mi búsqueda.

¿Alguien sabe cómo "taco" llegó a designar palabras *malsonantes, groseras u ofensivas*?

Comment: Tambièn existe la acepcciòn de "taco" como zapato especial para jugar futbol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pues nos vamos a tener que ir bastante lejos, porque resulta que el *Diccionario de Autoridades* (tomo S-Z, 1739) ¡ya incluye esta acepción!

> TACO. Vale también voto, juramento, ò porvida.

Y para que quede claro a qué se refiere, véase la definición de *porvida*:

> PORVIDA. Juramento ò blasphémia que se dice jurando por la vida de Dios ù de sus Santos.

Es decir, el significado original más que a los tacos se refería a las [blasfemias](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5g5ODQI) ("palabra o expresión injuriosas contra alguien o algo sagrado"), que por entonces podrían sonar incluso peor al oído que cualquier taco de hoy día.

El ejemplo que expone del *Diccionario de Autoridades* es del siglo XVII y se encuentra en el CORDE:

> *Y por durar mucho la pendencia y hacer tardanza mi amo, no cesaba el matasiete de echar tacos y porvidas.*
>
> Anónimo, "La vida y hechos de Estebanillo González", 1646 (España).

Aunque se puede encontrar una referencia anterior:

> *Paje: ¿Sois hidalgo?
>
>   Licas: De solar,
>
>   y aun de echar tacos también, [...].*
>
> Gaspar de Ovando, "La Atalanta. Comedia en tres jornadas", 1616 (España).

Y aun antes:

> *Así que, era protomédico, y alcalde y examinador mayor de los físicos que el diablo tenía en aquella provincia, y de sus arbolarios e oculistas e argebristas. Sus medicinas eran bramar y soplar y echar taco; y con este oficio vivía entre ellos y era tenido en mucho.*
>
> Gonzalo Fernández de Oviedo, "Historia general y natural de las Indias" 1535-1557 (España).

Con lo que llegamos hasta el siglo XVI ya con la expresión "echar tacos" incluida en el lenguaje. En todo caso, estos dos últimos ejemplos hay que cogerlos un poco con pinzas, porque pueden no significar lo que aquí tratamos. El ejemplo de 1646 está claro, pero los anteriores (cronológicamente) pueden significar, según el mencionado *Diccionario de Autoridades*:

> TACO. Entre los bebedores se llaman los tragos de vino, que beben sobre lo que han comido: y assi dicen, Echemos quatro tacos.
>   TACO. En la Germania significa el regueldo. [Sí, se refiere a [eructar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VjWD0tu).]

No puedo llegar más allá sin entrar ya en el terreno de las conjeturas. Se ve que la definición de "eructar" es al menos igual de antigua, por lo que puede haber influido en la que nos ocupa (por el tema de que salgan de la boca ruidos molestos). Pero no encuentro nada más. La definición que incluye Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611 incluye las acepciones de "el tarugo que el que apretamos alguna cosa", "la baqueta con que se aprieta el arcabuz después de cargado", y "el martillejo con que se juega a los trucos". No se me ocurre relación alguna, mas algo debe de haber.

Curiosa esta última acepción de Covarrubias, por cierto, pues ya en 1607 Oudin definía en su diccionario español-francés el juego de los "trucos" o "truecos" como *un sorte de jeu de billard*. Así que sí, se refiere a algo similar al billar de hoy día.

Comment: @walen pues sí, desde luego si la relación es esa es cuanto menos curiosa. Eso sí, dado que la acepción de "eructar" proviene de la germanía, ahí va a ser ya muy complicado saber qué motivos tuvieron para asignar el nombre de "taco" al eructo, como no sea que este sea simplemente la consecuencia natural después de echar unos cuantos tacos ("tragos"). Y si es así, ¿por qué se le llamó "taco" al trago? ¿Porque te dan un golpe al cuerpo igual que los tacos de billar?

Comment: Genial trabajo de investigación. Para mi la relación es clara: un eructo es algo malsonate y grosero. La asociación entre ese sonido asqueroso que sale por la boca y las palabras groseras no es forzada.